# Using deviation as surface color in a 3d pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I have measured data in the form of:
[x, y, z, z-Deviation]
I'm using pgfplot to render x,y,z in 3d and this works fine. But now, i would like to plot the z-deviation as color over the 3d map. Up to this point the color over the map is created from the value of the Amplitude (z-coordinate), but so far, i didn't figure out how to do this with a 4'th coordinate and relate this with the colorbar on the right.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lscape}


\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        colorbar = true,
        colorbar style = {
            ylabel = Standard Deviation
        },
        width = \textheight,
        xlabel = Angle,
        ylabel = OD\textsubscript{700},
        zlabel = Amplitude,
    ]
        \addplot3 [surf] file [
            x index = 0,
            y index = 1,
            z index = 2,
            z error index = 3,
            col sep = space
        ]
        {vorlage_messdaten.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following picture shows a cut through the upper picture. Here, I was able to show deviation as error bars. The deviation values vary in a range of 100 to 35000. I want to map this range to a color between red and green, where green means lowest deviation and red the highest one. In the final result, the color of the 3d image should show the deviation as a gradient between green and red to give a clear overview of the area with lowest and highest deviation.
[image]

Comment: are you looking for something like `point meta` key

Comment: this key looks promising, but how can i use it for the color mapping?  At the moment I'm slayed by the scope of the manual:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out:) I used traffic light colors for the different deviations:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lscape}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            colorbar = true,
            colorbar style = {
                ylabel = Standard Deviation
            },
            colormap = {newmap}{
                color(0cm) = (green);
                color(1cm) = (yellow);
                color(8cm) = (red);
            },
            width = \textheight,
            xlabel = Angle,
            ylabel = OD\textsubscript{700},
            zlabel = Amplitude
        ]
            \addplot3[surf] table [
                x = Angle,
                y = OD700,
                z = Amplitude,
                point meta = \thisrow{Deviation},
                col sep = space
            ]
            {vorlage_messdaten.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]